# How to test Range Object in jasmine?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I am writing a test about Range object. My code is similar to the following.

```
Test = function () {};

Test.prototype.test = function () {
  if (window.getSelection) {
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
    // then some code;
  } else if (document.selection) {
    range = document.selection.createRange();
    //then some code;
  return 'haha';
}

it('should create range object', function () {
  var myTest, result;
  myTest = new Test();
  spyOn(myTest, 'test').andReturn('haha');
  result = myTest.test();
  expect(result).toEqual('haha');      
});
```

When I run the test, it throw an error: `INDEX_SIZE_ERR: INDEX_SIZE_ERR: DOM Exception 1`

But my code works well in the browser.

Then I found something about [getRangeAt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/getRangeAt) and [rangeCount](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/rangeCount).

> Before the user has clicked a freshly loaded page,  the rangeCount is 0.

Then I try to add the code like `$(document).click();`, the rangeCount is still 0...

and it still throw `INDEX_SIZE_ERR: INDEX_SIZE_ERR: DOM Exception 1`

So, the question is : how can I normally test Range Object in jasmine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to mock `window.getSelection` or `document.selection.createRange`, so that the original methods will not be called.

```
it('should create range object', function () {
  var myTest, result;
  myTest = new Test();
  //mock the select function so that it will return "haha" when getRangeAt is called
  var range = 'haha';
  var rangeObject = {
    getRangeAt: function(){return range}
  };
  spyOn(window, 'getSelection').andReturn(rangeObject)
  spyOn(myTest, 'test').andReturn('haha');
  result = myTest.test();
  expect(result).toEqual('haha');      
});
```

Comment: But range object is created by Selection object using the `window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0)`. This way can not create a range object. right?

Comment: The range object is the one that the first spy returns. Will update the code to make it more clear.

Comment: Perhaps I know what you mean. If I need to use property like `range.startOffset` and method like `range.insertNode()`, I should make a fake Range Object. `getRangeAt: function () { return { startOffset: 0, insertNode: function () { return; }} }` Right?

Comment: Yes, you mock `getRange` to return an object that itself can return mocks and so on.